# How to make a service luanch null or 0 if a method param is false

Tags: angular, rxjs

Guys I have to send a request by a service when `IsConfigurated == true` but In same cases I don't want to make my condition on compliterPage.ts so I have to do that on my service, I have tried same solution like:

```
ChangeACCStatus(IsConfigurated){
    let dataStruct = {
      SessionId: localStorage.getItem('SessionId')
    }
    if(IsConfigurated){
      return this.http.post(`${this.CommandeURL1}/TryToChangeAccAlarm`, JSON.stringify(dataStruct), this.httpOptions);
    }else{
      return null
    }
  }
```

but here I found that error when I subscribe that method in case the return is null

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null

and I have tried to make the return at 0 and here I faced:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable | 0'

finally I used as return `new Observable(null)` and here I can't reach to the subscribe at all.

Rq: Myservice call in compliterPage.ts is:

```
this._compileSerivce.ChangeACCStatus(this.CurrentInfo['IsACCAlarmConfiguredByGPRS']).subscribe(contactServiceData =>{
                console.log(contactServiceData)
                if(contactServiceData != (null||0)){
//Do samething}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to it.

#### Option 1: RxJS [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) function

You could return `null` or `false` using RxJS `of` function.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

ChangeACCStatus(IsConfigurated): Observable<any> {
  if (!!IsConfigurated) {
    const dataStruct = { SessionId: localStorage.getItem('SessionId') };
    return this.http.post(`${this.CommandeURL1}/TryToChangeAccAlarm`, JSON.stringify(dataStruct), this.httpOptions);
  }
  return of(null); // <-- or `of(false)`
}
```

Note that this will trigger the `next` callback of the subscription as if it's a valid response. So you need to handle it.

#### Option 2: RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant

You could return RxJS `EMPTY` constant that will trigger the `complete` callback of the subscription and complete.

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

ChangeACCStatus(IsConfigurated): Observable<any> {
  if (!!IsConfigurated) {
    const dataStruct = { SessionId: localStorage.getItem('SessionId') };
    return this.http.post(`${this.CommandeURL1}/TryToChangeAccAlarm`, JSON.stringify(dataStruct), this.httpOptions);
  }
  return EMPTY;
}
```